# Api doesn't update record vu creates new

Tags: api, rest

I have a civicrm-application that gets updates trough an external rest-api call. But there's something odd happening.

````
Request:
```
api_key=76d9f1d3h4c87c2465a8a305b6fe&key=487e30c9219952143657f779&json={"first_name":"Sebastian","last_name":"Vyaene","birth_date":"01-01-1992","gender_id":2,"custom_5":"B380-A003-G164-W878","custom_6":null,"custom_7":null,"preferred_language":"nl_NL","phone":"0477745678","custom_8":{},"custom_18":[],"contact_type":"Individual","sequential":1,"custom_14":0,"id":420564,"custom_10":0,"api.Address.create":{"contact_id":"$value.id","street_address":" ","postal_code":"9000","city":null,"location_type_id":1,"id":396363},"api.Email.create":{"contact_id":"$value.id","email":"sebastian@marlon.be","id":426290},"api.Phone.create":{"contact_id":"$value.id","phone":"0477745678","id":101260},"api.Membership.create":{"contact_id":"$value.id","membership_type_id":1,"join_date":"2017-10-16","start_date":"2017-10-16","end_date":"2018-10-16","source":{},"custom_17":"B380-A003-G164-W878","id":362337}}&entity=Contact&action=create
````

```
this is an create action, but there's already an id present, so there should be an update. But as you can see in the response, the id is ignored and another contact is created, what is not the behaviour we want.

````
Response:

```

{"is_error":0,"version":3,"count":1,"id":481202,"values":[{"id":"481202","contact_type":"Individual","contact_sub_type":"","do_not_email":"0","do_not_phone":"0","do_not_mail":"0","do_not_sms":"0","do_not_trade":"0","is_opt_out":"0","legal_identifier":"","external_identifier":"","sort_name":"Vyaene, Sebastian","display_name":"Sebastian Vyaene","nick_name":"","legal_name":"","image_URL":"","preferred_communication_method":"","preferred_language":"nl_NL","preferred_mail_format":"Both","hash":"0326647eddd86831d8e1454926e8a2c5","api_key":"","first_name":"Sebastian","middle_name":"","last_name":"Vyaene","prefix_id":"","suffix_id":"","formal_title":"","communication_style_id":"","email_greeting_id":"1","email_greeting_custom":"","email_greeting_display":"","postal_greeting_id":"1","postal_greeting_custom":"","postal_greeting_display":"","addressee_id":"1","addressee_custom":"","addressee_display":"","job_title":"","gender_id":"2","birth_date":"1992-01-01","is_deceased":"0","deceased_date":"","household_name":"","primary_contact_id":"","organization_name":"","sic_code":"","user_unique_id":"","created_date":"2018-08-20 10:04:48","modified_date":"2018-08-20 10:04:48","api.Address.create":{"is_error":0,"version":3,"count":1,"id":396363,"values":[{"id":"396363","contact_id":"481202","location_type_id":"1","is_primary":"1","is_billing":"0","street_address":" ","postal_code":"9000","manual_geo_code":"0"}]},"api.Email.create":{"is_error":0,"version":3,"count":1,"id":426290,"values":[{"id":"426290","contact_id":"481202","location_type_id":"","email":"sebastian@marlon.be","is_primary":"","is_billing":"","on_hold":"","is_bulkmail":"","hold_date":"","reset_date":"","signature_text":"","signature_html":""}]},"api.Phone.create":{"is_error":0,"version":3,"count":1,"id":101260,"values":[{"id":"101260","contact_id":"481202","location_type_id":"","is_primary":"","is_billing":"","mobile_provider_id":"","phone":"0477745678","phone_ext":"","phone_numeric":"","phone_type_id":""}]},"api.Membership.create":{"is_error":0,"version":3,"count":1,"id":362337,"values":[{"id":"362337","contact_id":"481202","membership_type_id":"1","join_date":"2017-10-16","start_date":"2017-10-16","end_date":"2018-10-16","source":"Array","status_id":"2","is_override":"","owner_membership_id":"","max_related":"","is_test":"0","is_pay_later":"0","contribution_recur_id":"","campaign_id":""}]}}]}

```
````

Request Id:  420564
Response Id: 481202

I've looked at the call for hours and i can't find the problem. Anyone else who can help?

I'm currently on 4.6.36 and drupal 7.59. But as a test i upgraded to 5.2.1 and the same problem occures.

Comment: The request string looks correct. Can you share a part of the code where you call the rest api?

Answer (score 1):

The snippet looks correct to me, Can you try using 'contact_id' instead of 'id' as sometimes it did work for me. I am having hard time to recollect the scenario why i had to use 'contact_id' over 'id'.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: That doesn't help unfortunately.